# Widget is stretch in home screen.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, widget

I have use below code.

In my manifest file.

```
 <receiver android:name=".ButtonWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will also process our self created action -->
                <action android:name="<package name>.android.widget.buttons.ButtonWidget.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/appwidget" />
        </receiver>
```

In my `xml` folder `appwidget` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"

>
</appwidget-provider>
```

and below is my `widget_layout` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/widget_ibtn_onoff"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/widget"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

In `drawable` `widget` size is as below.

```
drawable-hdpi - 60px
drawable-ldpi - 30px
drawable-mdpi - 40px
drawable-xhdpi - 80px
```

In my galaxy nexus is look like below screenshots.
[image]

Thanks
Girish

Comment: Its show perfect in android 2.3 but not perfect in android 4+  may its use padding or margin so its stretch but I do not know about this space.\

Comment: What are the dimensions (width X height) of your image?

Comment: I have already write in my question.
drawable-hdpi - 60px
drawable-ldpi - 30px
drawable-mdpi - 40px
drawable-xhdpi - 80px

Comment: Yeah, but you have give only one value. So, I am assuming `width == height`

Comment: Yes width and height is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/widget_ibtn_onoff"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/widget" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah Its perfect. Thanks a lot shoe rat. Which size I have to define if I want 2x2 widget?

Comment: I have set it to 80 dp and its look fine.